# How to change the background color of \framebox?

Tags: diagrams, shading

I'm trying to change a picture drawn using the plain picture environment and I need to change the background color of certain `\framebox` to lightgrey. Is it possible?

I know that there are more powerful environment like `tikz`, but the figure is quite complex, and I prefer to change the less I can.

For example, supposing to have this LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{picture}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hp]
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
      \begin{picture}(7,3)(0,0)
        \put( 4,3){\framebox(3,3){World}} % background = grey ??
        \put( 0,3){\framebox(3,3){Hello}}
      \end{picture}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

producing this figure:

[image]

How can I change that code in order to get this result:

[image]

with the minimal effort in term of code changes ?

I tried to use `pstricks` that is something like a superset of `picture` package, but I wasn't able to solve my issue...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is possible with `\colorbox` and the package `xcolor`. You need to add only one macro and to set `\fboxsep` to 0pt.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{picture,xcolor}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}[hp]
        \begin{center}
          \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
          \begin{picture}(7,3)(0,0)
            \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
            \put( 4,3){\colorbox{gray!20}{\framebox(3,3){World}}} % 
            \put( 0,3){\framebox(3,3){Hello}}
          \end{picture}
        \end{center}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `xcolor` also has the command `\fcolorbox{<frame color>}{<background color>}{<text>}`, which does this directly.  According to the documentation, it takes care drawing the frame so that it is not overwritten by the background, so perhaps it is better than combining `\colorbox` and `\framebox`.  Though I see now that the OP is using a particular version of `\framebox` in the `picture` package, so maybe this option isn't available here.

Comment: @RyanReich: Yes, and there's a little more that is required to use `\fcolorbox` to match `\framebox` - see my answer.

Comment: Yes I agréé with your comments

Comment: This is probably the less painful solution, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 7):

With a little bit of massaging, you can still use the `picture` environment to do this, without having to resort to more advanced techniques (like [`tikz/pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{picture}% http://ctan.org/pkg/picture
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hp]
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{15mm}
      \begin{picture}(7,3)(0,0)
        \put( 4,4.5){\fcolorbox{black}{black!15}{\smash{\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{World}}}}} % background = 15% black
        \put( 0,3){\framebox(3,3){Hello}}
      \end{picture}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}​
```

The above uses `\fcolorbox` from [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) to fill the background with some colour (`black!15` or 15% black in this case). The whole idea is to typeset something without height/width in a box that has a `3cm` width/height (or `15mm` `\fboxsep`<sup>*</sup>).

This answer attempts to duplicate the behaviour of `\framebox` from the `picture` package. @Altermundus' answer to add a background via the traditional `\colorbox` from `xcolor` is much cleaner.

<sup>*</sup> I guess, if more precision is required, `\setlength{\fboxsep}{\dimexpr 15mm-\fboxrule\relax}` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: I chose @Altermundus' answer because it requires less code changes, but thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](11,5)
        \psset{linestyle=dashed,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5}
        \psTextFrame[fillcolor=red](0,0)(5,5){Counter}
        \psTextFrame[fillcolor=blue](6,0)(11,5){Terrorist}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the original `\framebox`es were set at `(3,3)` and `\unitlength` was `1cm`, you could duplicate this behaviour: Use `\psset{...,unit=1cm}` and `\psTextFrame[..](0,0)(3,3){...}`, ...

Comment: @Werner: I will use `\psset{unit=0.6cm}` to get the same dimension.

Comment: Right, I was too hasty in my comment there...

Comment: @CounterTerrorist: This solution is a bit too far from the original for me, anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: @digEmAll: I just show some options that you can adjust. :)