# Background color for fancyvrb

Tags: color, backgrounds, fancyvrb

For reasons unclear to me, fancyvrb doesn't have a background option. However, the minted package, which it is based on, has one, which suggests it should not be too difficult to add.

The relevant code from `minted.sty` might be

```
\newenvironment{minted@colorbg}[1]{
  \def\minted@bgcol{#1}
  \noindent
  \begin{lrbox}{\minted@bgbox}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}}
 {\end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \colorbox{\minted@bgcol}{\usebox{\minted@bgbox}}}
```

I've only a sketchy idea what this code is doing, but I think it is defining the `bgcolor` option.

Both [How to change the background color of \framebox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38083/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-framebox), and [Background color in Verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15940/background-color-in-verbatim) seem relevant, but don't answer this question, at least the way I would like.

I also found http://groups.google.com/group/latexusersgroup/browse_thread/thread/c8c2e5dd1e9ff5cf, which has the following code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancybox, fancyvrb, calc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{colframe}{%
  \begin{Sbox}
    \begin{minipage}
      {\columnwidth-\leftmargin-\rightmargin-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-4pt}
    }{%
    \end{minipage}
  \end{Sbox}
  \begin{center}
    \fcolorbox{black}{LightSteelBlue}{\TheSbox}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}  
  \begin{colframe}
    \begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
      auto eth0
    \end{Verbatim}
  \end{colframe}
\end{document}
```

For some reason this produces a double line round the box, but is in the ballpark of what I want. I would prefer a bgcolor option like `minted` has, so one can do something like the following code. I spent some time fiddling with this, but quickly realised I had no idea what I was doing. Maybe I'll learn how to program in LaTeX someday, but it probably won't be today. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\usepackage{minted} % syntax coloring.
\newminted{c}{frame=single, bgcolor=bg}
\begin{document}
\begin{ccode*}{}
for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
    x[i];
\end{ccode*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27673/background-overflows-when-using-rounded-corners-for-listings-package-listings

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Did you mean to point me to mdframed? Or something else?

Comment: You can use the package `framed` in combination with the `etoolbox` command `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`.

Comment: Be aware that the background colour option in minted is implemented quite badly. It breaks under various circumstances. I have no idea how to implement it better, though (but TikZ could help …).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks for the comment. How could TikZ help? And did you ask for feedback/suggestions about the `minted` background thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


\makeatletter
\newif\ifFV@bgcolor
\newbox\FV@bgbox
\define@key{FV}{bgcolor}{\FV@bgcolortrue\def\FV@bgcolor{#1}}

\def\FV@BeginVBox{%
  \leavevmode\ifFV@bgcolor\setbox\FV@bgbox=\fi
  \hbox\ifx\FV@boxwidth\relax\else to\FV@boxwidth\fi\bgroup
  \ifcase\FV@baseline\vbox\or\vtop\or$\vcenter\fi\bgroup}
\def\FV@EndVBox{\egroup\ifmmode$\fi\hfil\egroup
  \ifFV@bgcolor\colorbox{\FV@bgcolor}{\box\FV@bgbox}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{BVerbatim}[bgcolor=LightSteelBlue]
abc
def
\end{BVerbatim}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Add options to `BVerbatim` to have a fixed width instead of the minimum one.

Change the code into

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifFV@bgcolor
\newbox\FV@bgbox
\define@key{FV}{bgcolor}{\FV@bgcolortrue\def\FV@bgcolor{#1}}
\define@key{FV}{framecolor}{\FV@bgcolortrue\def\FV@framecolor{#1}}
\def\FV@framecolor{white}

\def\FV@BeginVBox{%
  \leavevmode\ifFV@bgcolor\setbox\FV@bgbox=\fi
  \hbox\ifx\FV@boxwidth\relax\else to\FV@boxwidth\fi\bgroup
  \ifcase\FV@baseline\vbox\or\vtop\or$\vcenter\fi\bgroup}
\def\FV@EndVBox{\egroup\ifmmode$\fi\hfil\egroup
  \ifFV@bgcolor\fcolorbox{\FV@framecolor}{\FV@bgcolor}{\box\FV@bgbox}\fi}
\makeatother
```

to get a new key `framecolor` (default white, so no frame):

```
\begin{BVerbatim}[bgcolor=LightSteelBlue,framecolor=black]
abc
def
\end{BVerbatim}
```

### Comments on the code

Let's look at the code for adding a background color (the extension for the frame color is very similar).

I add a conditional (`\ifFV@bgcolor`) and a box register (`\FV@bgbox`) and a key for the `FV` family; when the user says `bgcolor=somecolor`, the conditional will be set to true and `somecolor` is stored in `\FV@bgcolor`.

Then I redefine `\FV@BeginVBox` which is responsible for starting the box for a `BVerbatim` environment; its definition starts with

```
\leavevmode\hbox...
```

so what I do is to change it into

```
\leavevmode\ifFV@bgcolor\setbox\FV@bgbox=\fi\hbox...
```

In this way, when the conditional is true, the box will be stored in our new register, instead that typeset immediately.

Now the end part: `\FV@EndVBox` usually ends with

```
...\hfil\egroup}
```

where this `\egroup` closes the `\hbox` construction; if the conditional is true, this wouldn't typeset the box, so I make it into

```
...\hfil\egroup
\ifFV@bgcolor\colorbox{\FV@bgcolor}{\box\FV@bgbox}\fi}
```

which will typeset the box over a suitably colored background.

Comment: egreg: With the following the result is rather weird (no margins and no background color). And because of \colorbox, the outcome doesn't break across pages. `\CustomVerbatimEnvironment{myverbatim}{Verbatim}{%
  numbers=left,numberblanklines=false,
  firstnumber=last,frame=single,rulecolor=\color{purple},
  framerule=1pt,framesep=7pt,formatcom=\color{blue},
  xrightmargin=\rightmargin,xleftmargin=\leftmargin,
  commandchars=\|\(\),showtabs=true,commentchar=&%
}` I am soryy, it won't fit here properly.

Comment: That's impressive. Would you consider annotating your answer for the TeX-illiterate? I find LaTeX code hard to understand. Also, is `BVerbatim` necessary because it puts the environment in a TeX box? Lastly, how would one put a line around the frame? `frame=single` does not do anything.

Comment: @AhmedMusa The background color is intended only for the BVerbatim environment. I'm afraid that patching `fancyvrb` to allow for multipage background colored verbatim environments is too difficult.

Comment: @FaheemMitha `frame=single` doesn't work with `BVerbatim`. However I'll add a small patch to my answer.

Comment: Nice work. Could this reasonably added to `fancyvrb` functionality, or is it too fragile? Also, maybe annotating everything is too much work, but how about a sample?

Comment: Sorry to resurrect a very old post, but is it possible to get this working for inline Verb usage, i.e. within \Verb++?

Comment: With `newverbs` you can do `\makeatletter
\newverbcommand{\cverb}
  {\begingroup\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}\setbox\verbbox\hbox\bgroup\color@setgroup}
  {\color@endgroup\egroup\fcolorbox{.}{LightSteelBlue}{\usebox\verbbox}\endgroup}
\makeatother` and use `\cverb+abc+`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer to your question, just a way how to get rid of the double frame. To get rid of the "inside" frame, just remove the `[frame=single]` optional argument of the `Verbatim` environment, that is, use

```
\begin{Verbatim}
```

instead of

```
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
```

To get rid of the "outside" frame, replace `\fcolorbox` by simply `\colorbox`:

```
\colorbox{LightSteelBlue}{\TheSbox}
```

In that case, you should also change the calculation of the minipage width, since you do not need to subtract the thickness of the frame.  The complete code without the double frame will then look like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancybox, fancyvrb, calc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{colframe}{%
  \begin{Sbox}
    \begin{minipage}
      {\columnwidth-\leftmargin-\rightmargin-4pt}
    }{%
    \end{minipage}
  \end{Sbox}
  \begin{center}
    \colorbox{LightSteelBlue}{\TheSbox}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}  
  \begin{colframe}
    \begin{Verbatim}
      auto eth0
    \end{Verbatim}
  \end{colframe}
\end{document}
```

That will create:

[image: color box around verbatim]

Comment: Thanks Jan. Actually, I would like the option of having *one* frame. Of course, this would need to be on the boundary where the color ends, otherwise it will look funny. Is this possible. BTW, I'm surprised nobody has answered the original question. I thought it seemed straightforward for people with the necessary knowledge/expertise. Perhaps I'm missing something.