# Seemingly trivial: verbatim, newenvironment, and colorbox

Tags: color, environments, verbatim

I am, once again, trying to achieve what seems like a trivial goal. I want to use  `\newenvironment` to define a verbatim environment *with* a background color. I need to define my own environment because I need to run extra commands when opening the environment.

Here's what I have so far:

```
\newenvironment{response}{%
  % here, run extra commands, mostly related to \tikzmark and other extra legwork
  \verbatim
}{
  \endverbatim
}
```

This works fine. I tried the following to add a background color.

- Define a background color for FancyVrb ([Background color for fancyvrb](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39276/background-color-for-fancyvrb)), but then if I put `\begin{Verbatim}` and `\end{Verbatim}` in lieu of `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim`, this no longer works,
- Playing myself with `\color@setgroup` and `\color@endroup` but these do not seem to be exposed by the xcolor package.
- Using an lrbox, but again, any pair of `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}` that go *across* the environment are rejected (possibly because of `\verbatim`?)

I'm quite puzzled now and would love to have any pointers. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: the first comment has the solution, namely my failing to use \VerbatimEnvironment!

Comment: For `fancyvrb`, you need to use `\VerbatimEnvironment` before the `\begin{Verbatim}`.  That tells `fancyvrb` to detect the name of the current environment, and look for the end of *that* environment, rather than looking for a literal `\end{Verbatim}`.

Comment: I'd recommend trying `tcolorbox`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `fancyvrb`, you need to use `\VerbatimEnvironment` before the `\begin{Verbatim}`. That tells `fancyvrb` to detect the name of the current environment, and look for the end of that environment, rather than looking for a literal `\end{Verbatim}`.

You will probably want to use a proper framing package to provide the background color...that way you won't have to worry about coming up with your own solutions for pagebreaks and will have access to a lot more features.  You may want to take a look at `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`.  An example with `mdframed` is below.  `tcolorbox` has built-in solutions for a lot of use cases; one of those might give you most or all of what you need.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{response}%
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green]
    \begin{Verbatim}}
  {\end{Verbatim}%
    \end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{response}
<Text>
\end{response}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is much simpler than whatever I had come up with. Your solution does add quite some extra blank space before and after the environment, though. (Trying to figure out why right now.)

Comment: Found it. It was the skipabove and skipbelow settings of mdframed.

Answer (score 2):

First, here is a solution that uses only the `xcolor` package and the standard `verbatim` environment.  But it is not a new environment, per se, and so does not directly answer the OP's question (for that, see below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\fboxrule=1pt
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{minipage}{3in}
\color{red!90}
\begin{verbatim}
\verbatim <Text>
Here
%$#@&^* \macros
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}}
\fcolorbox{cyan}{blue!10}{\box0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To create an environment as desired by the OP, I adapted color into the syntax employed by the `verbatimbox` package, and created the `cverbbox` environment, which stores your verbatim content in a user-named box that is exactly as wide as the content (plus boxsep and boxrule).  It comes with an optional argument and 4 mandatory arguments:

```
\begin{cverbbox}[options]{boxname}{text color}{box color}{frame color}
...
\end{cverbbox}
```

where the options are the same as already work in `verbatimbox` environments (in this MWE, I used the option to make the verbatim `\tiny` and added a bullet before each row).  It uses `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` in the standard manner to set frame offset and rule thickness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{cverbbox}[5][]{%
  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{0}%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
% THE FIRST #1 ACCOUNTS FOR NON-PRINTING COMMANDS; THE SECOND #1 IS FOR
% PRINTED OPTIONAL MATERIAL
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \global\edef\sv@name{\@macro@name{#2}}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxColor{#4}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxFColor{#5}%
  \@ifundefined{\sv@name content}{%
    \expandafter\newsavebox\expandafter{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
  }%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\edef\csname\sv@name\endcsname{\usebox{%
  \csname\sv@name content\endcsname}}%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\color{#3} \verbatim
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup%
  \setbox1=\hbox{%
    \colorbox{\cverbboxColor}{\box0}}%
  \global\sbox{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
    {\fboxsep=\fboxrule\colorbox{\cverbboxFColor}{\box1}}%
}
\makeatother
\fboxrule=1pt\fboxsep=3pt\relax
\begin{document}
\begin{cverbbox}[\tiny\textcolor{black}{$\bullet$}]{\mycvbox}{red!80}{blue!10}{cyan}
\verbatim <Text>
Here
%$#@&^* \macros
xa
\end{cverbbox}
x\fbox{a}\mycvbox\fbox{b}x
\end{document}
```

[image]