# Typeset source code with tcolorbox

Tags: sourcecode, tcolorbox

I want to typeset source code with `tcolorbox` package. How is possible in this package not to create static boxes but rather boxes that adjust according to the width of the code I write both vertically and horizontally? Also I want if a line is too long to break into a new line. Can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `tcolorbox` and its `listings` library you can use `\newtcblisting` to define a new environment for listings (using behind the scenes the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package); if you use the `hbox` option for the `tcolorbox`, its width will dynamically adapt to the width of its content but, alas!, now the box doesn't admit page breaks and also automatic line breaks are not very well supported (the code will break if `breaklines=true` was passed as an option for the listing, but the box now won't behave nicely for long lines).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}{
  listing only,
  hbox,
  colframe=cyan,
  colback=cyan!10,
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    columns=fullflexible
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}
int main(int ac, char *av[]) 
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}
int main(int ac, char *av[], char **ep,char *av[], char **ep) 
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps then you can have breakable boxes with automatic line breaks by default, and selectively add the `hbox` option if you need variable width for short listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[1][]{
  listing only,
  breakable,
  colframe=cyan,
  colback=cyan!10,
  listing options={
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    columns=fullflexible
  },
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox]
int main(int ac, char *av[]) 
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}
int main(int ac, char *av[],int ac, char *av[],int ac, char *av[],int ac, char *av[],int ac, char *av[],int ac, char *av[]) 
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
int main(int ac, char *av[]) 
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `tcolorbox` package also offers interaction with [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) (another popular package for listings); minted, however, doesn't support automatic line breaking. A little example using now the `minted` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}{
  colframe=cyan,
  colback=cyan!10,
  listing only,
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=cpp,
  minted options={fontsize=\small,linenos,numbersep=3mm},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}
int main(int ac, char *av[]) 
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}
int main(int ac, char *av[], char **ep,char *av[], char **ep) 
{
  printf("Hello, World");
  return 0;
}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I second the integration of the listings package. It gives many possibilities to typeset the code in a more readable way.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it further. Why the "breaking" don't work if you modify the box? Also do you know another package to typeset source code in the way I want it? Shouldn't be the default way to write code like the one I ask for?

Comment: @Adam You're welcome. To answer: 1) When `hbox` is used the boxing mechanism used (which allows the width calculation) doesn't support page breaks. 2) The most popular packages are `listings`, `minted` and `fancyvrb` (`tcolorbox` offers interaction with the first two); none of them will do exactly all what you want; the closest results can be achieved using my second example and manually using the `hbox` option in case of short listings that won't have page breaks. 3) No, I don't think it shouldn't be the default. Many people don't like colorized boxes of variable width for their listings.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I didn't mean color boxes should be the default. I meant all the properties I mentioned should be. I don't like color boxes either (I use white color in `tcolorbox` package)! I just like the freedom for custom boxes it provides.

Comment: @Adam Ah, I see; in any case, boxes of variable width is also not a widely used feature. Listings allowing page breaks and automatic line breaks can be achieved using the `listings` package or `tcolorbox` with its `listings` library.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know how to do it in `tcolorbox`, I showed at [Seemingly trivial: verbatim, newenvironment, and colorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/seemingly-trivial-verbatim-newenvironment-and-colorbox/171749#171749) how to make colored verbatim boxes with my `verbatimbox` package.  I haven't yet upgraded the package to provide these by default, so they are herein contained in the preamble.

Note that this answer does **NOT** support automatic line breaking.  And being in a box, it does not support page breaking either.

I modify that answer (which provided a single environment) by providing two environments, `cverbbox` and `mycverbbox`, the latter of which allows you to specify the unique name of the box holding the result.  I also show, in the 3rd example, how to number code lines through the use of the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mycverbbox}[5][]{%
  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{0}%fx
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
% THE FIRST #1 ACCOUNTS FOR NON-PRINTING COMMANDS; THE SECOND #1 IS FOR
% PRINTED OPTIONAL MATERIAL
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \global\edef\sv@name{\@macro@name{#5}}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxColor{#3}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxFColor{#4}%
  \@ifundefined{\sv@name content}{%
    \expandafter\newsavebox\expandafter{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
  }%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\edef\csname\sv@name\endcsname{\usebox{%
  \csname\sv@name content\endcsname}}%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\color{#2} \verbatim
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup%
  \setbox1=\hbox{%
    \colorbox{\cverbboxColor}{\box0}}%
  \global\sbox{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
    {\fboxsep=\fboxrule\colorbox{\cverbboxFColor}{\box1}}%
}
\newenvironment{cverbbox}[4][]{%
  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{0}%fx
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
% THE FIRST #1 ACCOUNTS FOR NON-PRINTING COMMANDS; THE SECOND #1 IS FOR
% PRINTED OPTIONAL MATERIAL
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \global\edef\sv@name{theverbbox}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxColor{#3}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxFColor{#4}%
  \@ifundefined{\sv@name content}{%
    \expandafter\newsavebox\expandafter{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
  }%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\edef\csname\sv@name\endcsname{\usebox{%
  \csname\sv@name content\endcsname}}%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\color{#2} \verbatim
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup%
  \setbox1=\hbox{%
    \colorbox{\cverbboxColor}{\box0}}%
  \global\sbox{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
    {\fboxsep=\fboxrule\colorbox{\cverbboxFColor}{\box1}}%
}
\makeatother
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

\fboxrule=3pt\fboxsep=1pt
\begin{cverbbox}[\scriptsize\textcolor{black}{$\bullet$}]{red!80}{blue!10}{cyan}
here is \verbatim Text
Here
%$#@&^* \macros
xa
\end{cverbbox}
\fbox{An} inline verbatimbox\theverbbox is here.

\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=3pt
\begin{cverbbox}{blue}{cyan!40}{cyan}
here is frameless colorboxed \verbatim Text
by setting \fboxsep to 0pt.
No conditioning is performed with
an \optional argument
\end{cverbbox}
\theverbbox


\fboxrule=1pt\fboxsep=3pt\relax
\begin{mycverbbox}[\tiny\textcolor{black!50}{\tiny\makebox[4ex][r]{%
  \theVerbboxLineNo:~}}]{black}{blue!10}{cyan}{\mycvbox}
      subroutine cubic (p,q,r,rts)
c     SOLVES CUBIC EQUATION x^3 + px^2 + qx + r = 0
c     WITH REAL COEFFICIENTS.  SOLUTION MAY BE COMPLEX.
      implicit none
      double precision p,q,r,rts(2,3)
      double precision Ar, Ai, arg, ang, Br, Bi, SUMr, SUMi, DIFr,
     &                 DIFi, a,b, radicand, term,   PI
      PARAMETER (PI=3.14159 26535 89793 23846 d0)
c
      a = (3.d0*q - p**2)/3.d0
      b = (2.d0*p**3 - 9.d0*p*q + 27.d0*r)/27.d0
      radicand = b**2 /4.d0 + a**3 /27.d0
      if (radicand .ge. 0.d0) then
        term = -b/2.d0 + sqrt(radicand)
        if (term .ge. 0.d0) then
          Ar = term**(1.d0/3.d0)
        else
          Ar = -(-term)**(1.d0/3.d0)
        end if
        Ai = 0.d0
        term = b/2.d0 + sqrt(radicand)
        if (term .ge. 0.d0) then
          Br = -(term**(1.d0/3.d0))
        else
          Br = (-term)**(1.d0/3.d0)
        end if
        Bi = 0.d0
      else
        arg = (sqrt((b/2.d0)**2 - radicand))**(1.d0/3.d0)
        ang = atan(sqrt(-radicand)/(-b/2.d0))
        if (ang .lt. 0.d0) ang = ang + PI
        ang = ang/3.d0
        Ar = arg*cos(ang)
        Ai = arg*sin(ang)
        Br = Ar
        Bi = -Ai
      end if
      SUMr = Ar + Br
      SUMi = Ai + Bi
      DIFr = Ar - Br
      DIFi = Ai - Bi
      rts(1,1) = SUMr - p/3.d0
      rts(2,1) = SUMi
      rts(1,2) = -(SUMr - DIFi*sqrt(3.d0))/2.d0 - p/3.d0
      rts(2,2) = -(SUMi + DIFr*sqrt(3.d0))/2.d0
      rts(1,3) = -(SUMr + DIFi*sqrt(3.d0))/2.d0 - p/3.d0
      rts(2,3) = -(SUMi - DIFr*sqrt(3.d0))/2.d0
      return
      end
c********************************************************************
\end{mycverbbox}
\mycvbox

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that frameless boxes can be obtained by setting `\fboxrule` to `0pt`.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful but it is a bit complex for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Understood.  The preamble definitions can be just cut and paste into your document, but I understand the desire for simplicity.  Cheers.