# Framing and colorizing a LaTeX command

Tags: color, verbatim, framed

I normally use `\verb|\LaTeXe|` to typeset the command `\LaTeXe` in my document. But now I want to frame or/and colorize the command `\LaTeXe`. How can we do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{text}\\ % without \verb is ok
\textcolor{blue}{\verb|\LaTeXe|}\\ % this is illegal, but I want to colorize the command \LaTeX2e
\fbox{text}\\ % without \verb is ok
\fbox{\verb|\LaTeXe|} % this is illegal too, but I want to frame around the command \LaTeXe. So how can I do that?
\end{document}
```

Comment: One example would be to use `\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{\string\LaTeX2e}}` and/or `\fbox{\texttt{\string\LaTeX2e}}`, as suggested in [How to put `\verb` command inside of `\textbf` block?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24574/5764) There is also the option of using [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb), or [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings), or ...

Comment: @Werner I actually use `listings` package but use it whenever I need to include long code. However, I like your solution `\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{\string\LaTeX2e}}` and `\fbox{\texttt{\string\LaTeX2e}}`. It does not require additional packages (y)

Comment: These kinds of things are quite easy to do with the `verbatimbox` package.  You can search the site, yielding things like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141100/getting-verbatim-with-soft-grey-background-as-in-tex-stackexchange/141101#141101 or this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174455/typeset-source-code-with-tcolorbox/174472#174472