# Which LyX template for technical software documentation with source code layout?

Tags: lyx, code, lyx-layouts

I am looking for a LyX template to write technical documentation including source code boxes, with colored syntax rendering like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174455/typeset-source-code-with-tcolorbox) for LaTeX that makes use of the `minted` package.

More than a template with nice code rendering, I would like one including a source code [layout](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Concepts), in order to have the [WYSIWYM](http://wiki.lyx.org/Glossary/WYSIWYM) metaphor working in my documentation that includes source code.

As a note, the LyX WYSIWYM unique feature makes me run away from markdown solutions like [sphinx-doc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.1/rest.html#source-encoding) or [MkDocs](http://www.mkdocs.org/). I want documentation to be cool to write - without making use of pdf rendering to read it easily.

As a workaround, I use the zim wiki which can export to LaTeX, but then the code boxes in the generated pdf are ugly.