# styling verbatim with background color

Tags: pandoc

I am using pandoc to convert Markdown documents containing code blocks to PDF, and the intermediate TeX surrounds the code with `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}`. How can I stylize and format these sections to have a background color or a frame around it? I've tried `fancyvrb`, but the background color does not extend behind the text itself.

I've tried using the `verbatim` package and after reading the manual was able to modify `\verbatim@processline` to change the font color or add text in front of each line: `\def\verbatim@processline{\fbox{\$ \the\verbatim@line}\par}`. I would like to this for the entire chunk and modify other properties (frame, centering, etc) in the future. I thought the best way to do this would be to add a `\begin{shaded}` into  `\verbatim` and add `\end{shaded}` into `endverbatim`. However, I run into an error when I do that:

```
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim{{\begin\{shaded\}}\begingroup\@verbatim 
\frenchspacing\@vobeyspaces\verbatim@start}
\def\endverbatim{\endtrivlist\endgroup{\end\{shaded\}}}
\makeatother
```

And the error message:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
l.1 \begin{verbatim}
```

1. Is there a way to insert enclose the verbatim text in an environment that I can stylize later?
2. If not, is there a better way of stylizing the `verbatim` environment? I cannot change to `listings` or similar packages that use `\begin{lstlisting}` since pandoc automatically inserts `\begin{verbatim}`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor, framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{255,0,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{verbatim}
Shade this text block
Shade this too
\end{verbatim}

\begin{shaded}
\begin{verbatim}
Shaded text here
And also here
\end{verbatim}
\end{shaded}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you truly need a `verbatim` environment? For example, are you using any particular characters that are otherwise disallowed? Or are you merely interested in a `typewriter` style formatting of the text?

Comment: pandoc automatically uses a `verbatim` environment when converting from Markdown

Comment: You can probably change what Pandoc does; it's worth looking into that. (In the worst case you can completely redefine the meaning of `verbatim` in the preamble that Pandoc lets you add.)

Comment: Does this answer help?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/seemingly-trivial-verbatim-newenvironment-and-colorbox/171749#171749

Comment: Actually, I realized that I can specify a `--listings` argument while calling pandoc which uses the listings package instead of `verbatim` and that helped my issue a lot!