# Create a new environment to display a framed Python interactive session

Tags: beamer, environments, tcolorbox, pythontex

I want to display an interactive Python session inside a box in BEAMER.

[image: Expected result]

As my presentation has many slides like this I thought it would be convenient to create a new environment, but when I try to compile the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{boxsession}
  { \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue,colback=blue!5!white,notitle,size=small] \begin{pyconsole} }
  { \end{pyconsole} \end{tcolorbox} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Lists}
\begin{boxsession}
foo = [1, 2, 3]
bar = foo 
baz = foo[:]
foo[-1] = -99
foo
bar
baz
\end{boxsession}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.32 \end{frame}
                
?
```

I also tried to use `environ` to no avail:

```latex
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{boxsession}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue,colback=blue!5!white,notitle,size=small]
    \begin{pyconsole}
      \BODY
    \end{pyconsole}
  \end{tcolorbox}}
```

Any ideas how to get around this error?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455300

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are processing text, that contains special characters, you need to use `\VerbatimEnvironment`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{boxsession}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue,colback=blue!5!white,notitle,size=small]\begin{pyconsole}}
  {\end{pyconsole}\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Lists}
\begin{boxsession}
foo = [1, 2, 3]
bar = foo 
baz = foo[:]
foo[-1] = -99
foo
bar
baz
\end{boxsession}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Update: Changing the font

`pyconsole` uses `fancyvrb` internally (see sec. 10.4.6 of the pythontex manual), so you have to pass through font settings that are understood by `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{boxsession}[1][fontsize=\normalsize]
{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue,colback=blue!5!white,notitle,size=small]\begin{pyconsole}[][#1]}
{\end{pyconsole}\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Lists}
\begin{boxsession}[fontsize=\tiny]
foo = [1, 2, 3]
bar = foo 
baz = foo[:]
foo[-1] = -99
foo
bar
baz
\end{boxsession}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to change the font size through an optional parameter? I tried this `\newenvironment{boxsession}[1][\normalsize]` but got an error: `\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}`

Comment: @Tonechas – See update

Comment: You made my day! I wish I could upvote more than once.