# How can we Define our own Simple Environment for Source Code?

Tags: environments, sourcecode, fbox

Inside of our document we wish to define a new environment for blocks of source code

```
\newenvironment{srcblock}%
  % Define the environment
```

Later, we will use the environment:

```
\begin{srcblock} % use the environment
  % source code here
\end{srcblock}
```

We seek the following behavior:

- Each line in a src code block is numbered
- The font used for a src code block is monospaced
- A border is drawn around a code code block, much like `\fbox` does
- Each code block "floats" to a position so that it will fit all on one page.

Comment: What will `srcblock` contain in terms of characters? `verbatim`-like content, perhaps (symbols like `#`, `_`, `$`, `^`, ...)?

Comment: Did you already check the `listings` package? This should be straight-forward with it. Just read the manual.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Variation on my answer here: [Seemingly trivial: verbatim, newenvironment, and colorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/seemingly-trivial-verbatim-newenvironment-and-colorbox/171749#171749).  It requires a small modification to my `verbatimbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,caption,lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{cverbbox}[5][]{%
  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{0}%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
% THE FIRST #1 ACCOUNTS FOR NON-PRINTING COMMANDS; THE SECOND #1 IS FOR
% PRINTED OPTIONAL MATERIAL
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \global\edef\sv@name{\@macro@name{#2}}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxColor{#4}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxFColor{#5}%
  \@ifundefined{\sv@name content}{%
    \expandafter\newsavebox\expandafter{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
  }%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\edef\csname\sv@name\endcsname{\usebox{%
  \csname\sv@name content\endcsname}}%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\color{#3} \verbatim
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup%
  \setbox1=\hbox{%
    \colorbox{\cverbboxColor}{\box0}}%
  \global\sbox{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
    {\fboxsep=\fboxrule\colorbox{\cverbboxFColor}{\box1}}%
}
\makeatother
\fboxrule=1pt\fboxsep=3pt\relax
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\begin{cverbbox}[\textcolor{black}{\scriptsize\theVerbboxLineNo~~}]{\mycvbox}{red!80}{blue!10}{cyan}
\verbatim <Text>
Here
%$#@&^* \macros
xa
\end{cverbbox}
\centerline{\mycvbox}
\caption*{My code chunk}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This approach is not a simple environment but a standard `minted` environment nested in you own float environment. Not exactly the asked but:

> **☑**  Each line in a src code block is numbered (*optionally*)
>
> **☑** The font used for a src code block is monospaced (*and syntax highlited*)
>
> **☑** A border is drawn around a code code block, much like `\fbox` does (*with top caption inside using `\stdcaption`*, for a botom caption outside the box use `\caption`*)
>
> **☑** Each code block "floats" to a position (*concretely to top of a new page*) so that it will fit all on one page.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm, paperheight=5in,paperwidth=5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\stdcaption\caption
\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{fancycode}{t}{loa}
\floatname{fancycode}{LaTeX code}

\begin{document}


\begin{fancycode}
\stdcaption[Basic Structure]{The basic structure of a \LaTeX\ document.}
\begin{minted}[linenos,bgcolor=orange!05]{latex}
    \documentclass{article} 
    \begin{document}
    \end{document}
\end{minted}
\end{fancycode}

\begin{fancycode}
\stdcaption[Preamble]{The \LaTeX\ preamble to do a \texttt{fancycode}.}
\begin{minted}[linenos,bgcolor=cyan!10]{latex}
    \usepackage{minted}
    \usepackage{float}
        \floatstyle{boxed}
        \newfloat{fancycode}{t}{loa}
        \floatname{fancycode}{LaTeX code}
\end{minted}
\end{fancycode}

\lipsum[1-2]

\listof{fancycode}{Code examples}

\end{document}
```