# Adding a small colored rounded box around inline text

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to write a command using TikZ to produce a small rounded and colored box around a piece of text, inside sentence? I know the `\framedbox` command gives a rectangle around a piece of text (but not a rounded rectangle as far as I know).

I guess one could also adjust the color of the background when using framebox (using tips from answers to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38083/17858) question), but I don't think it could help with other factors such as the box's edge-width, the amount of roundness, etc.

The following picture was produced with Inkscape for the purpose of the question.

[image]

Comment: How about `tcolorbox`? Or `tikzmark`?

Comment: possible duplicate : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458864/138900

Answer (score 4):

Either use `TikZ` directly or `tcolorbox` with `\tcbox` and a lot configurable settings.

If such boxes should appear more than once, a `\newtcbox` is appropiate, setting the options there and just saying `\inlinebox{foo}` etc.

As can be seen from the direct usage of `\tcbox` that the margins are too wide, but the `\inlinebox` has a nicer look, there the margins are set with `left=...` and `right=...` and `boxsep=...`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\inlinebox}[1][]{enhanced,
 box align=base,
 nobeforeafter,
 colback=cyan,
 colframe=Green4,
 size=small,
 left=0pt,
 right=0pt,
 boxsep=2pt,
 #1}

\begin{document}

Hello \tcbox[enhanced,box align=base,nobeforeafter,colback=cyan,colframe=Green4,size=small]{World} -- what do you expect from the year \inlinebox{2019}?


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `tikzmark`, which less options than `tcolorbox`, but allows you to connect different boxes and also detect the mode you are in (text vs. math etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
Here is some text and \tikzmarknode[fill=cyan,fill
opacity=0.3,draw=green!60!black,thick,rounded corners,inner sep=2pt,text
opacity=1]{test}{something about relativity}.
\[\tikzmarknode[fill=cyan,fill
opacity=0.3,draw=green!60!black,thick,rounded corners,inner sep=2pt,text
opacity=1]{testeq}{E~=~m\,c^2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[thick,cyan,latex-latex] (test.-5) to[out=-90,in=0] (testeq.east);
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]